# zip creation issue with Python 2.6.6

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have code to create a `test.zip` using python 2.6.6 as below, and creating a zip too.

But inside test.zip I could see one more test.zip, with 0/1 MB size. I am not sure how to fix or what I am missing.

```
def createZip(path, ziph):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(folder, file), os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder,file),path), compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)


zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('/home/stbUpgrade/tmp/downLoad/test.zip', 'w')
createZip('/home/stbUpgrade/tmp/downLoad/', zipf)
zipf.close()
```

Comment: Could some one please check and update

Comment: I am just guessing you need to have the handle outside something like `zipfile.ZipFile('/home/stbUpgrade/tmp/test.zip', 'w')`? Otherwise, try to skip that file in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks Nishant, yeah I did the same to skip the file in the loop and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You zip the folder into a file, which is part of that folder. `zipfile.ZipFile()` will create an empty zip file, and thus you get an empty zip file in your `test.zip`.

You should place your `test.zip` into a folder outside of your zipped folder (e.g. your `tmp` folder).

BTW: You should use `with` for the case of errors:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('/home/stbUpgrade/tmp/test.zip', 'w') as zipf:
    createZip('/home/stbUpgrade/tmp/downLoad/', zipf)
```

Comment: Thanks , My requirement is to produce the same zip which I got, would you suggest any change in the code to achieve it?